# Cucumber - Serenity execute directly pass all test but execute with command line compile with error

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I try to introduce me in Cucumber and Serenity with Java using IntelliJ.

I try to execute the class that contains directly and apparently it works fine [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fuid.png)

But when I open the report it show 3 test but with the broken scenario [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsAhO.png)

I try to figure out but I see the configuration is correct and when I run with `mvn clean verify` command the data in example section don't work I'll show the structure of folders [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2VGp.png) and show the output of the command line [in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtAwW.png)

I really really appreciate any contribution and help and I don't find any solution of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the code / text to your question instead of using screenshots? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hi, i has rebuild the proyect with a specific folder strucuture based on a tutorial of cucumber a serenity and it works, and thanks for future requests i put the information like you said to me thanks

Comment: Happy to hear you solved it. If possible please mark the question as resolved.